# HTML Button can't control "on focus" functionality

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, button

Confused... I've tried CSS and JQuery and I just can't seem to get focus functionality to work properly on my HTML BUTTONs.  This is Firefox 54.

All my buttons have a grey background which goes light blue colour on "hover". Text is black. These colours appear to be "default".

I *have* managed to get rid of the dotted line box surrounding the text on focus of the button by going

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

but if I go, for example,

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}
```

... on focus, the text doesn't go green and the background doesn't go red.
I've also tried:

```
button :focus {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

... no effect.
I've also tried detecting a focus event by going

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $( 'button' ).focus( function(){
        console.log( '£ button got focus' );
    });
    ...
```

... nothing happens when I put the focus on any buttons!

I have naturally also tried googling and searching on here.  I seem to be missing something fundamental! I've tried looking through any CSS which could be interfering with "normal" mechanisms, to no avail.

Anyone got any idea what's going on?

Comment: button :hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

Comment: I'm not looking for a reaction on hover.  I'm looking for a reaction on focus.

Comment: yes, but in fact is the same, think in css not in jquery

Comment: `button :focus {`  if it is the button that should have the focus for the rule, then you need to remove that whitespace between the two, as whitespace denotes a child, not a logical AND.

Comment: @Taplar... ah... many thanks, this appears to be it!  Any idea why I might be getting zero response from the JQ code?

Comment: What do you mean zero response?  the `focus()` as you have it is setting up an event handler to do something on focus, of which isn't doing anything with the css of the element.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I am getting no response when I focus on any button: the `console.log` message is not being printed out...!

Comment: Ah... worked it out: in fact at the point I inserted this JQ focus callback all buttons were disabled... this project involves a lot of dynamic loading and enabling of disabled elements... If I put in the focus callback AFTER things have been made visible it works.  I've been surprised more than once by this "undynamic" or "non-retrospective" functioning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried editing your code a little bit and I believe the end result is what you are looking for.
You can take a look at the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/c9mbtrz0/

Ultimately, what you have to do for the CSS and JS part is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').focus(function() {
    console.log('£ button got focus');
  });
});
```

```css
button:focus {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
Test
</button>
```

Comment: You can check the JS console logs to see that it actually works, by the way.

Comment: Yes, as you have written it it works fine.  In my code, however, I am not getting any console output on focusing on any buttons.

Comment: So then the question would be what is different from this code and your code, as this works.  @mikerodent

Comment: Your jQuery code probably has issues @mikerodent. Replace your jQuery code with mine and give it a try. Alternatively, add your entire jQuery code into jsFiddle so that we can take a look. You may be missing something.

Comment: Yes, it was a code issue: see my latest comment under the question.  Everything sorted now.  Thanks to you and everyone else.